# Downloading ServiceNow data into a CSV file using Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, csv, soap, wsdl, servicenow

Can someone please tell me how to use SOAP and WSDL functionality along with ServiceNow in order to download data into a CSV file. I'm using Anaconda version 3.5.2

A sample script would be really helpful

Downgrading is not an option for me.

Comment: This is far too broad. We're not going to write your code for you. You need to read [help] and [mcve].

Comment: @MorganThrapp  Im sorry you feel that way. I cant find any documentation related to its use with versions 3 and above, so I asked.

Comment: What about [this documentation](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=SOAP_Direct_Web_Service_API)? That looks a lot like SOAP documentation for ServiceNow. The Anaconda version doesn't matter, it's all just Python.

Comment: Thanks @MorganThrapp but the Python Web Services Client Examples mentioned here use SOAPpy which is not compatible with the python version that I'm using.

Comment: No, that documentation doesn't mention anything about a specific python soap library. The example does, but any SOAP library will work. Library recommendations are off topic for SO however, so I would try google. Again, you need to try some stuff on your own.

Comment: AFAIK, soappy is old (and arguably, so is any service still using SOAP, ugh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had a requirement at my work to download and process a service-now report.
You can do it either using `SOAP` , `REST` or `WSDL`.
I am using `REST`. Not sure if that will help.

You need to `postfix` download type after table name. For e.g. `CSV` in below example.
Rest of the URL for report is same as you would download report manually from `servicenow`.

Here is a working code that downloads a report in `CSV` format. 
Report URL  and ID will need to be changed as per your organization.

```
import requests
import getpass


url = "https://yourcompany.service-now.com/sys_report_template.do?CSV&jvar_report_id="1234567890abcdefg"

uname=raw_input("Enter Username: ")
pswd=getpass.getpass(prompt='Enter Password: ', stream=None)

r=requests.get(url, auth=(uname, pswd))



if r.status_code==requests.codes.ok:
    print("Requests made a connection.\n")
    f=open(r'C:\dump.csv', 'w')
    f.write(r.content)
    f.close()

else:
    print("\nAn error occured while establishing a connection.")
    print("Status code returned: ",r.status_code)

c=input("\nEnter a key to exit.\n")
```

Comment: Thank you! @Anil_M

Comment: I Tried to download data but instead of downloading table values it downloads source code, could you please suggest, i am using URL that i  copied from filter that i created in service now (Copy Query URL)

Comment: Can you post Query URL?, Also , what version of Service-Now are you using?